# Maven + Cucumber4 + Spring Integration - unable to execute cucumber runner cases

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, junit4

I am unable to execute cucumber spring integration test using mvn test. Please refer pom.xml below -

I am using cucumber-spring, cucumber-java8, cucumber-junit. 
When I try to run mvn test or mvn clean install features are not running.

```
//Code
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>both</parallel>
                <threadCount>4</threadCount>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*RunCucumberTest.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please review the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask specifically the "Help others reproduce the problem" section.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove vintage engine (which is responsible to run old junit 3/4 tests in new junit 5 platform, your old tests will not be picked. It it junit vintage engine that detects these tests and run on new platform.

Unfortunately cucumber is still on junit 4 so those are not picked.